# Debugging connect syscall with strace – what does @"sun_path" mean?

Tags: sockets, unix, connect, strace, unix-socket

I've got two programs in different languages attempting to connect to a local abstract socket on a Linux system. One of the two is failing. I am having difficulty determining why. I just want to know what the one difference I can find in the `strace` output means, so I can fix it.

The working one has this `strace` output:

```
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0)     = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"qwertystop.bus.8"}, 19) = 0
```

The nonworking has this `strace` output:

```
[pid  6307] socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0) = 13
[pid  6307] connect(13, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="qwertystop.bus.8"}, 19) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

There are three differences: The nonworking one is from a program with multiple pids, the return value of the `connect` call is different, and the working one has a `@` before the `sun_path` string. I presume that whatever causes the `@` to be missing is also what caused the failure, since it makes little sense for socket connection to not work in a process just because it was started by a different process.

---

(I am explicitly not requesting a general solution to "connect to an abstract socket", which is why I am not stating the languages. Mostly because this is homework and I refuse to create a situation which might tempt me to copy code directly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meaning determined. It means the string is preceded by a null byte. Or possibly just a non-printing character, or  it's signifying that the socket is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Linux thing, I think.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html.  It should be under "abstract socket".

Comment: The `@` symbol appears nowhere in the linked document.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought you got that from the previous answer about the null-byte.  The null byte at the beginning is the linux-ism.  [https://superuser.com/questions/381262/linux-init-local-socket-with](https://superuser.com/questions/381262/linux-init-local-socket-with).

Sorry if I was unclear.